# Meaning of "Meeting agenda"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I don’t really understand what a *meeting agenda* is.  I don’t know if it is possible to use *meeting agenda*

1. when you have to register all the topics (conclusions, ideas, members, date, etc.) of the meeting,
2. or whether *meeting agenda* can only be used for the planning that goes before the meeting.

What is a suitable expression to name this type of record sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The agenda contains all the topics you want to discuss in the meeting. You write an agenda before the meeting, usually to inform the participants about what you want to talk about.

If there are other topics covered in the meeting that were not part of the agenda, then you will include these in the "minutes of the meeting" or the protocol of the meeting".

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Thank you! _Minutes of the meeting_ is the expression I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The items to be discussed are called the *agenda*. The record of who was there, any discussion and conclusions at the meeting are contained in [*minutes*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minute--3).

*Agenda* is properly a plural (of *agendum,* thing to be done), although since such lists are generally headed simply "Agenda", it's come to mean the list itself rather than the items within the list.